# why am I not able to fetch data by id in flask?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I have written below flask functions to create new store, get list of stores, and get store by ID. Please see below functions

```
import uuid
from flask_smorest import abort
from flask import Flask, request
from db import *

app = Flask(__name__)



@app.get("/store")
async def get_stores():
    return {"stores": list(stores.values())}


@app.post("/store")
async def create_store():
    store_data = request.get_json()
    store_id = uuid.uuid4().hex
    new_data = {**store_data, "id": store_id}
    stores[store_id] = new_data
    return new_data, 201


@app.post("/item")
async def create_item():
    item_data = request.get_json()
    if item_data["store_id"] not in stores:
        return abort(404,  "item not found")
    item_id = uuid.uuid4().hex
    item = {**item_data, "id": item_id}
    items[item_id] = item
    return item, 201


@app.get("/item")
async def get_al_items():
    return {"items": list(items.values())}


@app.get("/store/<string:item_id>")
async def getstore_items(item_id):
    try:
        return items[item_id]
    except KeyError:
        return abort(404,  "item id not found")


@app.get("/store/<string:store_id>")
async def get_stores_id(store_id):
    try:
        return stores[store_id]
    except KeyError:
        return abort(404,  "store id not found")
```

Passing JSON

```
    {
        "name": "sixerrrrr"
    }
```

To below function in POSTMAN is creating a new store successfully

```
http://127.0.0.1:5000/store
```

with below response in POSTMAN

```
{
    "id": "1fd69e85e9324011a54b7407d16268ac",
    "name": "sixerrrrr"
}
```

But when I execute `http://127.0.0.1:5000/store` as `GET`, I see empty list

```
{
    "stores": []
}
```

When trying to GET through ID, I get 404 error

```
http://127.0.0.1:5000/store/1fd69e85e9324011a54b7407d16268ac
```

error:

```
title>404 Not Found</title>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try
    again.</p>
```

I have already used print() in `def create_store()`, and I could see the new "name" and ID getting generated.

Not sure what is happening. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

```
    @app.get("/store/<string:store_id>")
async def get_stores_id(store_id):
    try:
        return stores[store_id]
    except KeyError:
        return abort(404,  "store id not found")
```

So in your context if you have a 404 error that means you have a KeyError.

```
@app.get("/store/<string:store_id>")
```

You are passing the store_id as a string.

If `store_id = 1` your request is code to be `stores['1']` and that's a KeyError.

Comment: Well, your suggestion helped me partially. Now my app looks like @app.get("/store/store_id") .Therefore, when I execute http://127.0.0.1:5000/store, its not an empty list anymore. But when fetching the store details with ID still throwing same error. Any further suggest

Comment: If still same error that means the key is still wrong. Focus on troubleshooting stores and what it really contains, for example add a ```print(stores)``` before the try loop

Comment: Its confusing, I added print(stores) in get_stores_id() function, and when I execute "http://127.0.0.1:5000/store/7659d135ae5648f981f1e5548dacd7e3" from POSTMAN, I do not see any output in my flask terminal, and I can say that my flask app is running with "flask run" command. That means the call is not even going inside that function.. any further suggestion?

Comment: Hi, data is now coming. I did went back and used <string:store_id>, and it is working for me.. I don't know what went wrong before...